# Parse XMLns file response PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to parse a response from a server but I am struggling with getting the information I want. I am trying to parse and save the username, username1234, to a variable, but I cannot parse it correctly and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

From using cUrl

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cas_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo nl2br("\nReply from curl: ").htmlentities($response);
    curl_close( $ch );
```

or file_get_contents

```
$resp = file_get_contents(htmlentities($cas_url));
```

I obtain the following:

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://somesite.edu'> 
<cas:authenticationSuccess> <cas:user>username1234</cas:user> 
</cas:authenticationSuccess> </cas:serviceResponse>
```

I have attempted to parse it using DOM where I saved the above reply to $xml but it returns nothing.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query("//cas:user");
if ($node->length) {
    echo $node[0]->textContent;
}
```

I have also tried registerXPathNamespace since I noticed it replied with xmlns, but I am sure I have done it incorrectly:

```
$XML_Obj = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
    $XML_Obj -> registerXPathNamespace('cas','http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas');
    foreach($XML_Obj->xpath('//cas:user') as $event){
        var_export($event->xpath('cas:serviceResponse'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `htmlentities()` on the output, that's just needed if you're going to display it in a browser. You don't want to do that if you're going to process as raw XML. In that case, [your first example](https://3v4l.org/k7tgZ) will work just fine.

```
$xml = file_get_contents($cas_url);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query("//cas:user");
if ($node->length) {
    echo $node[0]->textContent;
}
```

Comment: Oh man, can't believe that. I spent an hour trying to figure out why it wouldn't work. Thanks for the input!